# vue 3 with jsx, but the h or this.$createElement is not a functrion

Tags: vue.js, jsx

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "ref",
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  render(h) {
    return h("tag", {}, ["123"]);
  },
};
</script>
```

if I use the above code, some error h is not a funtion is in console, but if I use the code as follow:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "ref",
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  render(h) {
    return () => h("tag", {}, ["123"]);
  },
};
</script>
```

The element in page is not the 123 but string. It is not be covert to HTML element, how can i solve it.

```
function () { return h("tag", {}, ["123"]); }
```

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example using jsfiddle or codepen ?

Comment: @steady There's no JSX in your question despite the title/tag.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you have figured this out by now, but the `h()` function is now globally imported.

You would need to add to the top of this code snippet:
`import {h} from 'vue'`

You can see more about the why here: https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0008-render-function-api-change.md#globally-imported-h-function